# Bootstrap: show span with badge class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar and i add badge in my menu but it dose not show correctly.

[image]

but in bootstrap's site it show correctly, i couldn't find problem, there is my code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header"> ... </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> ... </ul>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a style="font-size: 18px;" href="#"><span style="font-size: 12px; background-color: #cc2200;" class="badge">358</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a></li>
                ....
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do it is due to the `font-family` or it is not getting enough space.

Try to give it a more space by increasing `width`, if doesn't work then it is default font style.